# SKScene Won't Present When SubView Is Added To View Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, sprite-kit, skscene

I tried to add a subview to my GameViewController (because I want to add a banner ad at the bottom). I created it as follows:

```
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        let subView = SKView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 415, height: 685)))
        view.addSubview(subView)
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFit
            subView.presentScene(scene)
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            view.showsFPS = false
            view.showsNodeCount = false
            view.showsDrawCount = false
            addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
        }
    }
```

This works initially - it presents my GameScene. But later, I ask my GameScene to present another subclass of SKScene that I created, which I call Shop, using the following code:

```
func initializeShop() {
    let shop = Shop(size: self.size)
    let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 0.1)
    self.view?.presentScene(shop!, transition: transition)
}
```

And it simply does not present. It remains on the current view.

This works completely fine if I do NOT add a subview to the initial view in the GameViewController, i.e.

```
   if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
            scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFit
            view.presentScene(scene)
            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            view.showsFPS = false
            view.showsNodeCount = false
            view.showsDrawCount = false
        }
    }
```

So it seems like there is some property of the GameViewController's default SKView that allows presentation, but not a subview. But I can't find any documentation that says that - from what I can tell, all SKViews should be able to present SKScenes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does addBannerViewToView?

Comment: That creates a separate subview which is also part of the of the gameviewcontroller's view. Disabling it does not change the result unfortunately